# saving and loading variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a game and its a type of game which takes hours to complete. Its a browser game. How can I store variables ( need to store 20-40 variables ) and load them using cookies ? ( so that I can access them even if browser is closed and opened again ). Please, I need help.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: You would be better off with localStorage and not cookies.

Comment: to save: `localStorage['save_var1'] = var1`, to load: `var var1 = localStorage['save_var1']`

Comment: Of course also check against undefined when loading for default values.

Comment: so If I have variables called food I would use: localStorage["save_food"] = food and to retrieve food = localStorage["save_food"] ?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using localStorage and not cookies. Pretty simple if you just do something like

```
//The defaults the user starts with
var _defaults = {  
   level : 1,
   userName : null,
   life : 100
};
//getting previous values from storage
var savedDetails = localStorage.settings ? JSON.parse(localStorage.settings) : {};
var settings = $.extend({},_defaults, savedDetails);

if(!settings.userName) {
//set username and save
    settings.userName = window.prompt("name"); 
} else { 
    //username is there so say hi
    console.log("Welcome back " + settings.userName);
}

//Save this back to the local storage since we made changes
localStorage.settings = JSON.stringify(settings);
```